# NHibernate QueryOver and selecting rows where a propery is an ILIST and the list count >= 1

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I would like to select rows for which the property Items which is an `IList` has rows itself. In SQL its easy count >= 1 but in NHibernate it eludes me.

Tried many ways

```
public class Sale
{
    private IList<Items> _items;

    public Sale()
    {
        _items = new List<Item>();
    }

    public Guid SaleId { get; set; }
    public string SaleNumber { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SaleDateTime { get; set; }

    public IList<Item> Items => _items;
}

public class Item
{
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

        var testdata = _session.QueryOver<Sale>()
            .Where(Restrictions.Ge(
                Projections.Property<Sale>
                (m => m.Items.Count), 1))
            .ReadOnly()
            .ListAsync();
```

`Count` is unrecognized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically if you did an inner join you wouldn't receive any `Sale` records back that do not have any `Item` records.

So as a really simple `QueryOver` you could do:

```
var sales = session.QueryOver<Sale>()
  .Inner.JoinQueryOver(x => x.Items)
  .Select(Projections.RootEntity())
  .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
  .List();
```

This is the resulting SQL:

```
SELECT this_.SaleId as saleid1_1_0_, 
  this_.SaleNumber as salenumber2_1_0_, 
  this_.Location as location3_1_0_, 
  this_.SaleDateTime as saledatetime4_1_0_ 
FROM Sale this_ 
 inner join Item item1_ on this_.SaleId=item1_.SaleId
```

Comment: Thank you Joe, I did do an inner join but it gives me one row for each item. I only want one row if there are any items. I even tried a distinct criteria on the join. I really only need the sale rows.

Comment: Joe my old join did not have the projection and transformation which seems to get rid of duplicate rows for the root entity 'sales' . So thank you.  I added the projection and transformation and I get the clean result now.